# How to get the zip-code using google-maps-api-3 in a text input autocomplete

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

How can I get the results from the autocomplete text input with the restriction of addresses?

I mean, I have a text input and I need to get the zip code of the place, but when I write an address, it give me many options, public places, general places, etc.. Only the name of the street (without the street prefix) and the complete street name gives me the ZIP Code.

The problem is that I get the zip code only when I write the prefix "street", otherwise doesn't work, that's why I would like to restrict the autocomplete results for only adddresses.

Sample:

Writting: Piccadilly Circus 5 --> I get the zip code,
5 Piccadilly Circus, Soho, Londres W1D 7ET, Reino Unido

Writting: Piccadilly Circus --> I can't get the zip code
Piccadilly Circus, Londres W1J, Reino Unido

Any idea? Thanks!

[link_code_here](http://jsfiddle.net/Xr8Lf/4/)

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="txtAddress">Write your address:</label>
    <input type="text" id="geocomplete" name="txtAddress"/>
</div>

    $(function () {
    $("#geocomplete").geocomplete({
        types:["geocode", "establishment"]
    })
    .bind("geocode:result", function (event, result) {
        //$.log("Result: " + result.formatted_address);
        alert("Result: " + result.formatted_address);
    })
    .bind("geocode:error", function (event, status) {
        alert("ERROR: " + status);
    })
    .bind("geocode:multiple", function (event, results) {
       alert("Multiple: " + results.length + " results found");
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm afraid there is nothing you can do

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I can help

```
    $("#geocomplete").geocomplete(
    { 
       types:["geocode", "establishment"]
    }
).bind("geocode:result", function(event, result){

  results = result.address_components;

  $.each(results, function( index, value ) {
     if(value.types == 'postal_code'){

         console.log(value.long_name); // here you get the zip code  
     }
  });
});
```